Local Storage Not Consistently Loading on Page Refresh
I have a form on my web page with two input elements and a button. I am using local storage to save the form inputs and reload them when the page is refreshed.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const txt = document.getElementById('txt');
    const type = document.getElementById('type');
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    // Load form inputs from local storage if available
    if (localStorage.getItem('txt') !== null) {
        txt.value = localStorage.getItem('txt');
        type.value = localStorage.getItem('type');
    }

    // Save to local storage
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.setItem('txt', txt.value);
        localStorage.setItem('type', type.value);
    });
});

The issue: Sometimes, when I refresh the page, the inputs do not load properly from local storage. However, if I do a hard refresh, the inputs load correctly.
I checked in the developer tools that the values are being saved properly after clicking the button. And this doesn't seem to happen in Firefox.
How can I can make the local storage load properly? Can someone please help fix it?

It sounds like the issue you're experiencing might be due to the timing of when the DOMContentLoaded event fires and when the inputs are populated. Sometimes, the input elements might not be fully ready when the event fires, causing the local storage values to not be set properly.

A good approach to ensure that your local storage values are correctly loaded is to handle both the DOMContentLoaded and pageshow events. The pageshow event is fired when the page is loaded from the browser cache, which can handle the cases where the DOMContentLoaded might not suffice.
Here's how you can modify your script to handle both events:
const loadFromLocalStorage = () => {
    const txt = document.getElementById('txt');
    const type = document.getElementById('type');

    if (localStorage.getItem('txt') !== null) {
        txt.value = localStorage.getItem('txt');
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('type') !== null) {
        type.value = localStorage.getItem('type');
    }
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadFromLocalStorage);
window.addEventListener('pageshow', loadFromLocalStorage);

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const txt = document.getElementById('txt');
    const type = document.getElementById('type');
    localStorage.setItem('txt', txt.value);
    localStorage.setItem('type', type.value);
});

